# Как выровнять по центру?

Tags: html, css

Есть `div` блок и 4х4 `div` блока в нём.

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yec0Lm1/)

1. Как выровнять текст по центру по горизонтали и вертикали ?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении текста блоки не съезжали?

Comment: по горизонтали и вертикали относительно чего?

Comment: @onmotion, div-блока "tile"

Comment: Все блоки должны быть выровнены, образовывать ровную сетку?

Comment: @onmotion, Да, всё верно. А текст, который будет внутри этих блоков не должен вызывать смещения этих же блоков.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/onmotion/3rn061de/ правда ответ уже дали альтернативный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `.tile:before{content: ''; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;height:100%;}`

2) `.tile` - `vertical-align: top;`

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 240);
}

.main {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3% auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(158, 158, 167);
    padding: 10px;
}

.tile {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tile:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile">something</div>
    <div class="tile"></div>

    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>

    <div class="tile">one more</div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>

    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! ......

Answer (score 0):

1) для того чтобы выровнять по центру можно воспользоваться двумя способами:

Первый (самый лучший) - воспользоваться flex

```
<div>
    <span>text</span>
</div>

div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Второй: сделать блок ячейкой таблицы и добавить к нему стиль vertical-align и text-align

2) По поводу блоков

Добавьте это к main

```
.main {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: .......Спасибо!